# Install packages from DVD repository in Docker image

Tags: docker, mount

I am trying to build a Docker image that needs to install some packages from a DVD iso but I cannot mount the iso inside the container.

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/devtoolset-7-toolchain-rhel7:latest
USER root
WORKDIR /home

COPY tools.iso ./
COPY tools.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN mkdir /mnt/tools && \
    mount -r ./tools.iso /mnt/tools && \
    yum -y install make && \
    umount /mnt/tools && \
    rm tools.iso
CMD /bin/bash
```

When I run `docker build` it returns the following error:

```
 mount: /home/tools.iso: failed to setup loop device: No such file or directory
```

I also tried to add the command `modprobe loop` before mounting the iso but logs says it returned code=1.

Is this the correct way to install packages from a DVD in Docker?

Answer (score 0):

In general Docker containers can't access host devices and shouldn't mount additional filesystems.  These restrictions are even tighter during a `docker build` sequence, because the various options that would let you circumvent it aren't available to you.

The most straightforward option is to write a wrapper script that does the mount and unmount for you, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -d tools ]; then mkdir tools; fi
mount -r tools.iso tools
docker build "$@" .
umount tools
```

Then you can have a two-stage Docker image where the first stage has access to the entire DVD contents and runs its installer, and the second stage actually builds the image you want to run.  That would look something like (totally hypothetically)

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/devtoolset-7-toolchain-rhel7:latest AS install
COPY tools tools
RUN cd tools && ./install.sh /opt/whatever

FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/devtoolset-7-toolchain-rhel7:latest
COPY --from=install /opt/whatever /opt
EXPOSE 8888
CMD ["/opt/whatever/bin/whateverd", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8888", "--foreground"]
```

The obvious problem with this is that the entire contents of the DVD will be sent across a networked channel from the host to itself as part of the `docker build` sequence, and then copied again during the `COPY` step; if it does get into the gigabyte range then this starts to get unwieldy.  You can use a `.dockerignore` file to cause some of it to be hidden to speed this up a little.

Depending on what the software is, you should also consider whether it can run successfully in a Docker container (does it expect to be running multiple services with a fairly rigid communication pattern?); a virtual machine may prove to be a better deployment option, and "mount a DVD to a VM" is a much better-defined operation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am going to test your solution as soon as possible. However, why are you suggesting a 2 stage image? Which are the benefits in this case? For what concern your last question, no its a simple service: my troubles are related to "how to run `yum install` with a DVD repo".

Comment: I'm assuming that the content on the DVD is "big", but is totally redundant with what actually gets installed.  In that case the two-stage build avoids having the second copy in the image you're actually using.  `yum` makes this a little trickier because you can't really isolate the installed package into a single directory that can get copied; the flip side of this is that you can COPY only the specific `.rpm` file(s) you need to install.